# Problem with data sent from android inside php file can't handle it

Tags: php, mysql, backend

I have a user name variable data sent from Android and then dealing with this data when I dealt with this data problem appeared briefly problem when I type if ($j = = $find _id)
I do not get the required data inside Android but if I replace the variable $find _id by 2, for example no problem occurs and I get the data what is the problem with this variable? 
Note Use an external server on a site 
[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn7Al.png)
[table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeEXJ.png)

```
// get_req.php
<?php
// include Marei DB Class 
include 'DB.php';
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$obj = json_decode($data);
$db = DB::getInstance();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$len= $db->getCount();
$movies = array();
$users = $db->table("requests")->Qget();
$username= "";


if(!isset($obj->{'user_name'})) {
//print json_encode(['status' => 0, 'message' => 'Username is Non !']);
}else{
$username = $obj->{'user_name'};
  //print json_encode(['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Username is Don !']);
}



$rows = $db->table('users')->get();

$filter_value1 = [];
$filter_value2 = [];

$count=0; 
$find_id=0;

foreach($rows as $row){
  $filter_value1[]=$row->user_email;
  $filter_value2[]=$row->id;
 // if($filter_value1[$i] == "gmal")
  if($filter_value1[$count]==(string)$username){
    $find_id=$filter_value2[$count];
  }
    // echo "$row->name <br>";
  $count++;
}
//echo($find_id);
$i = 0; 
foreach($users as $user){
    //echo $user->post_content;
    $j =  $user->user_id;
    if($j==$find_id){
    $movies[$i]['id'] = $user->id;
    $movies[$i]['user_id'] = $user->user_id;
    $movies[$i]['name'] = $user->name;
    $movies[$i]['title'] = $user->title;
    $movies[$i]['status'] = $user->status;
    $i++;
}

}

$index = 0;
if(isset($_GET['index'])){
    $index = $_GET['index'];
}

$end = $index + 3;

if($index>(count($movies) -1)){
     echo json_encode(array());
     exit;
}

if($end > (count($movies) -1)){
//  $end = count($movies) - 1;
    $end = count($movies);
}

$data = array();


for($i=$index;$i<$end;$i++){
    $movies[$i]['type'] = 'movie';
    $data[] = $movies[$i];
}

echo(json_encode($data));
```

Comment: what is value of  **$username** ? is it same as **user_email** ? because you are comparing  --> if($filter_value1[$count]==(string)$username)

Comment: i have puted in any mail is like mysql

Comment: $username contain email value ?